# sending two mail's back to back on a single click using sendmail function....?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

Please help me on

I am using sendMail function to send the mail. On button click I am sending the mail. but instead it is sending two mail's back to back on a single click and I dont find any reason for this so please help if anyone knows this problem, any help is appreciated, Thanks....

Below is my VB code to sendMail....

```vb
Protected Sub btnsend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _ 
    Handles btnsend.Click

    'Response.Write("<Script> alert('" & Request.QueryString("id").ToString() & "');</Script>")
    Dim str_smtpserver As String = DotNetNuke.Entities.Host.HostSettings.GetHostSetting("SMTPServer")
    Dim str_auth As String = DotNetNuke.Entities.Host.HostSettings.GetHostSetting("SMTPAuthentication")
    Dim str_uname As String = DotNetNuke.Entities.Host.HostSettings.GetHostSetting("SMTPUsername")
    Dim str_pass As String = DotNetNuke.Entities.Host.HostSettings.GetHostSetting("SMTPPassword")

    Dim str_sub As String = "Message "

    Dim tobody As String

    Dim value As String = Request.QueryString("id").ToString()

    Dim ds_staff = New DataSet()

    ds_staff = DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider.Instance().ExecuteDataSet("GetToEmailFromDB", value)
    tobody = "<table border='1px'>"

    tobody += "<tr><td style='width:90px;'>Name :</td><td>" & txtname.Text & "</td></tr>"
    tobody += "<tr><td style='width:90px;'>Email :</td><td>" & txtemail.Text & "</td></tr>"
    tobody += "<tr><td style='width:120px;'>Message :</td><td>" & txtmessage.Text & "</td></tr>"

    tobody += "</table>"

    fromid = "test@test.org"
    Dim rVal As String = DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail(fromid, ds_staff.Tables(0).Rows(0)("email").ToString(), "", "", DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailPriority.Normal, str_sub, DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailFormat.Html, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, tobody, "", str_smtpserver, str_auth, str_uname, str_pass)
    If (rVal = "") Then
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('Your message has been sent.');", True)
    Else
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('Invalid Email ID.');", True)
    End If

    Response.Redirect("home.aspx", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: have you already seen [Button click event handler firing twice](http://forums.asp.net/t/1056418.aspx/1)?

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is most likely attached several time to the button's click event.

Maybe you do in once in the aspx file and once in the code behind (OnInit?) file.